# Application failed 2 times due to AM Container, exited with exitcode -104

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark application with two input files and a jar file which is taken up from Amazon S3 bucket. I am creating a cluster using AWS CLI with `instance type` as `m5.12xlarge` and `instance-count` as `11` and spark properties as:

```
--deploy-mode cluster
--num-executors 10
--executor-cores 45
--executor-memory 155g
```

My spark job was running for some time and then it failed and restarted automatically and it ran again for some time and then it showed this diagnostics (pulled from the logs)

```
diagnostics: Application application_1557259242251_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1557259242251_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -104
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: Container [pid=11779,containerID=container_1557259242251_0001_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.4 GB of 1.4 GB physical memory used; 3.5 GB of 6.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1557259242251_0001_02_000001 :
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1557259242251_0001 finished with failed status
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1165)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1520)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/05/07 20:03:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/05/07 20:03:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-3deea823-45e5-4a11-a5ff-833b01e6ae79
19/05/07 20:03:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-d6c3f8b2-34c6-422b-b946-ad03b1ee77d6
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem?

I have tried change the instance type or lowering the executor memory and executor-cores but still the same problem keep on occuring.
Sometimes the same configuration settings terminates the cluster successfully and results are generated but many time these error are generated.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing more than 1 input file to the spark job. Make a jar and then execute it.

Step 1: How to make a zip file

```
zip abc.zip file1.py file2.py
```

Step 2: Execute job with a zip file

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --py-files /home/abc.zip /home/main_program_file.py
```